# Async/await not returning result at all

Tags: javascript, async-await

I don't really get the async/await method after trying to ask my lecturer and trying to surf on the web. I initially thought async/await can return me the desired outcome for my activity selection challenge, but it doesn't.

From this code given, i am trying to `console.log()` out the result from the function `selectPerformanceByFestivalId`, but then when i see the result, it only gives me an empty object as the result instead of an array of objects.

By right i was supposed to get something like this:

```js
[
  {
    "performanceid": "1234567890",
    "starttime": 1330,
    "endtime": 1530,
    "festivalid": "2234567891"
  },
  {
    "performanceid": "1234567891",
    "starttime": 1530,
    "endtime": 1630,
    "festivalid": "2234567891"
  },
  {
    "performanceid": "1234567892",
    "starttime": 1330,
    "endtime": 1530,
    "festivalid": "2234567891"
  },
  {
    "performanceid": "1234567893",
    "starttime": 1330,
    "endtime": 1530,
    "festivalid": "2234567891"
  },
  {
    "performanceid": "1234567894",
    "starttime": 1430,
    "endtime": 1530,
    "festivalid": "2234567891"
  }
]
```

But i got this as the result: `{}`.

Here is my current async/await code:

```js
async function sortPerformanceByFinishTime(endTime) {
    const filteredPerformance = await selectPerformanceByFestivalId;  //do a await to let the previous function execute first before continuing
    const storeArray = []   //create a new array to reorder the stuff again
    console.log(filteredPerformance);
};
```

This is how i did my `selectPerformanceByFestivalId`:

```js
// 1. selectPerformance to correctly select set of performance for computation
function selectPerformanceByFestivalId(performances) {
    const l = performances.length;  //length of performances
    const selectedPerformance = []; //create a new array selectedPerformance
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {   //iterate through all the festivalId
        selectedPerformance.push(performances[i]);  //push filtered performance into the array
    };
    return selectedPerformance; //return the array
};
```

`selectPerformanceByFestivalId` is supposed to hold the entire json result(which was the data above) and when i `console.log(filteredPerformance)`, i expected the same json result.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Please share code for `selectPerformanceByFestivalId` method as well.

Comment: Hi. I've edited my post already. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: If you are awaiting the `selectPerformanceByFestivalId` method it needs to be marked async and must return a promise. An example can be found at the URL https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in your code so you should not be using `async`/`await`. Also, you need to *call* `selectPerformanceByFestivalId` and pass an argument.

Comment: Couple of things. 
1. selectPerformanceByFestivalId seems to be doing a synchronous computation, is there any specific reason for await?
2. You are not invoking it, you are just referencing it

Answer (score -1):

You are giving a reference to a function object instead of calling it.

Change your line of code to

```
  const filteredPerformance = await selectPerformanceByFestivalId();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer a couple of questions. The function expects an argument which is not being passed. Also, it's not clear in the question as to how is `performances` going to be obtained in the caller method. Why does it have to async.

Answer (score -1):

I created a Plunk at https://plnkr.co/edit/OeJg8ISk8XHinuR3
using the example code that you have shared above. Couple of changes to your existing code.

1. Added async Keyword before the function `selectPerformanceByFestivalId`.
2. Added parens after the call to the function `selectPerformanceByFestivalId` in the function `sortPerformanceByFinishTime`